# For loop assigns wrong array index

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array with the following structure:

```
[10] => Array
    (
        [10] => test key
        ...
        [100] => test key
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [10] => test key
        ...
        [100] => test key
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [10] => test key
        ...
        [100] => test key
    )
...
```

This is the loop that I use in order to create such structure:

```
$array = array();
for ($x = 0.1; $x <= 1; $x+=0.1) {
    $index = $x*100;
    for ($z = 10; $z <= 100; $z+=10) {
        $array[(int)$index][$z] = 'test key';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the output that I receive looks like this once it is supposed to reach the 90 and 100 index:

```
[80] => Array
    (
        [10] => test key
         ...
        [100] => test key
    )

[89] => Array
    (
        [10] => test key
         ...
        [100] => test key
    )

[99] => Array
    (
        [10] => test key
         ...
        [100] => test key
    )
```

Why does it calculate the index to be 89 and 99? Shouldn't it be 90 and 100 respectively?

*edit
I am using floats as that's the measurement of percentages that we use to make some calculations. I know I could go by 10 increments as well, but that would require me to eventually divide by 100 again in order to get the float

Comment: [Read, learn and understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems); then appreciate that PHP rounds down when casting from float to int

Comment: But why are you using floats anyway?

Comment: why such a convoluted way of incrementing in 10's

Comment: I am using floats as that's the measurement of percentages that we use to make some calculations.

Comment: Use integers, then convert to floats only when you need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are using floats with `$x`... Just start at `10` and step by `10` until you hit `100`.

```
$array = array();
for ($x = 10; $x <= 100; $x+=10) {
    $f = ((float)$x) / 100.0; # calculate float value here
    for ($z = 10; $z <= 100; $z+=10) {
        $array[$x][$z] = 'test key';
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, what you are seeing is most likely due to floating-point arithmetic rounding.

Comment: I am using floats as that's the measurement of percentages that we use to make some calculations. I know I could go by 10 increments as well, but that would require me to eventually divide by 100 again in order to get the float

Comment: Got it... In that case, convert from `int` to `float` when needed. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it calculate the index to be 89 and 99? Shouldn't it be 90 and 100 respectively?

I think that it occurs because you use a decimal for the x value, why you don't use an integer value?

```
$array = array();
for ($x = 10; $x <= 100; $x+=10) {
    for ($z = 10; $z <= 100; $z+=10) {
        $array[$x][$z] = 'test key';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using floats as that's the measurement of percentages that we use to make some calculations. I know I could go by 10 increments as well, but that would require me to eventually divide by 100 again in order to get the float

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more modern syntax:

```
<?php

$array = [];
for ($x = 10; $x <= 100; $x+=10) {
    for ($z = 10; $z <= 100; $z+=10) {
        $array[$x][$z] = 'test key';
    }
}

print_r($array);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [70] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [80] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [90] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

    [100] => Array
        (
            [10] => test key
            [20] => test key
            [30] => test key
            [40] => test key
            [50] => test key
            [60] => test key
            [70] => test key
            [80] => test key
            [90] => test key
            [100] => test key
        )

)
```